# draw a line between to .png image in latex

Tags: latex

I put two *image.png* in my latex documnet using *\includegraphics*. Now I want to joint two points of these images together by a line. I wonder if it is possible to do so in Latex?

Comment: It is possible to draw lines in latex, for example using pictex (which I think is deprecated by now). But latex does not have any understanding of the contents of your image.  It would be probably much easier to use gimp or some other image manipulation program to draw a line inside your image.png.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: no it is impossible: as Gyro Gearloose had said LaTeX has no idea about the content of your png.

Second: sure you can ;-) A little cheat with `tikz`. You can connect two arbitrary points with an arrow (or a line).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
  \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark} % arrows in tex
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows}   % arrows in tex
  \usetikzlibrary{calc}     % (node)+(3cm,2cm)
  \tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{solidtex.png}
{\tikz\node[coordinate](start1){};}
\lipsum[2]
{\tikz\node[coordinate](end1){};}
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{solidtex.png}
\lipsum[3]

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, -latex, color=blue!15!red, yshift=1ex, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=1pt, line width=0.1cm]
  \path[->] (start1) edge [out=150, in=240] (end1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But it still connects the corners of the images. To connect points inside the pictures, you have to modify the coordinates manually e.g.:

```
  \path[->] (start1) edge [out=150, in=240] ($(end1)+(2cm,2cm)$);
```

or `pt`, `ex`, `mm` ect...

If you want line without arrow head, use:

```
  \path[-] (start1) edge [out=150, in=240] (end1);
```

---

**Note** that like labeling and referring figures, you have to run `latex` (or `pdflatex` or ...) twice.